# Is there any difference between "hostess" and "stewardess"?

Tags: difference

I was wondering when I should use these words: 'hostess', 'air hostess', 'stewardess' and 'flight attendant'. What are the differences between them?

Some examples:

> One of the conference hostesses was very young.
>
> That's why I also want to study several languages, to become an air hostess.
>
> She worked as an airline stewardess.

Which should I use in each case?

Should I use "hostess" or "stewardess" for the people who help at conferences?

Comment: *Flight attendant* is the preferred term nowadays because it's gender neutral. This is similar to *police officer* or *firefighter* which have largely replaced *policeman* and *fireman*. More generally, the difference between *stewardess* and *hostess* is the same as the difference between *steward* and *host* (consult a dictionary).

Comment: @Era Interestingly, the definition of host and hostess is different among many of the dictionaries I checked. Only the feminine hostess has the sense of steward or stewardess listed, and steward doesn't list host as a synonym. It's odd, although I only checked US English.

Comment: I presume the link between "hostess" and "stewardess" comes from airlines where the same people are handling both providing services to the passengers and maintaining order in the cabin. This was/is a stereotypically female job. I don't think i've ever heard "air host" or "air steward".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me as a native British English speaker, hostess implies hospitality - she would be there to make your experience a good one. She could be the hostess of a dinner party, or a conference, making sure that the visitors have enough drinks and answering their questions, basically just keeping them comfortable.

However, stewardess implies keeping people 'in order', 'controlling' the people, and so you would have a stewardess at a cycling race or to keep crowds under control.

However, as Era said, it's considered a little backwards to use *stewardess* and *hostess*.

Comment: I agree strongly with your first paragraph. As to your second, though, I think stewardess usually conjures up images of flight attendants, or maybe [cruise ship workers](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stewardess) – not cycling races or marathons.

Comment: @J.R. Actually I think that might be confusing two different senses of the word "steward". You can have an event steward that is responsible for managing the crowds at an event, for example: http://www.assetwatchltd.co.uk/training/event-steward-training/.

Comment: @ColleenV - I realize that's a valid usage of the word, but I don't think it's what most native speakers would think of – at least not initially.

Comment: @J.R I don't disagree for AmE, but I wonder if it's different in BrE.